# Htacess rewrite for AngularJs App

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help regarding AngularJs application. I need htacess file for HTML5Mode in AngularJS and Hashbang fallback. Can someone help me? Cuz i get %2F when i use backslash. I've been folowing along this tutorial but they use express.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-seo-with-prerender-io

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="WebApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="http://localhost/myapp/">
    <meta name="fragment" content="!" />
</head>
```

and this is my **mainjs**

```
var app = angular.module('WebApp', ['ngRoute']) 

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){ 

  $routeProvider.when('/', { 
    templateUrl : 'views/home.html', 
    controller: 'PageCtrl' 
  })

  $routeProvider.when('/about', {
      templateUrl : '/views/about.html',
      controller: 'PageCtrl'
  })


  $routeProvider.otherwise({
          redirectTo : '/'
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}]);



function PageCtrl($scope) { 
  // For this tutorial, we will simply access the $scope.seo variable from the main controller and fill it with content. 
  // Additionally you can create a service to update the SEO variables - but that's for another tutorial. 

}
```

and this is me trying to get **htacess** right

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^  index.html#! [L]
```

Comment: Please don't post cross site duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33591367/1190388

Comment: This is the exact same problem that I am facing on localhost Apache. Even if I get the navigation to work, it breaks on page reload. Not sure what will fix this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @hjpotter92 It seems like the link that you posted is broken. Can you please post the relevant link? This problem has been bugging me for a lot of time. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Devner The link is correct, but the question has been deleted: " deleted by Community♦ Dec 12 '15 at 9:26 (RemoveDeadQuestions)

This question was automatically deleted."

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thanks for the prompt reply. By any chance, do you happen to know of any working solution? I have tried out the solutions provided on other threads but they all seem to be obsolete and do not work with angular version 1.4.7 (this is what I am using).

Comment: @user3187715 You are seeing that %2F as it seems that you still have #/ in your hyperlink href atribute. Just remove that #/ and you will be good to go. For example: `<a href="about">About</a>`. But still, the main problem of page 404 persists.

Comment: @Devner I did suggest an answer on that [so] thread, but it seems that OP's (and likely, yours) issue is actually related to angular.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes, you are right. The question is about angular. I will try to look up your answer on SO & see if I can find it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is apache and encoded slashes. / is eacaped as %2f its code for slash. Allow encoded slashes on in your vhost file should solvle the problem.